# No results from SendGrid email activity API

Tags: api, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3, email-bounces

I'm using this documentation to try and receive bounce information from the SendGrid email activity API:

https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/getting-started-email-activity-api/#filter-by-bounced-emails

But it returns no results, despite having ~50 bounces showing on our dashboard (which are viewable from the "activity" section on the SendGrid web interface).

**Request:**

```
curl --request GET \
 --url 'https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/messages?limit=100&query=status%3D%22bounced%22' \
 --header 'authorization: Bearer <<TOKEN_REMOVED>>'
```

**Response:**

`{"messages":[]}`

Obviously <<TOKEN_REMOVED>> is our actual token when I'm running it :)

**Note -** when I use the `v3/suppression/bounces` endpoint to return *everything* it works fine (responds with a huge JSON of bounces), however I'd like to be able to use the more flexible `messages` endpoint for querying a specific email etc.

```
curl --request GET \
--url https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/suppression/bounces \
--header 'accept: application/json' \
--header 'authorization: Bearer <<TOKEN_REMOVED>>' \ 
--header 'content-type: application/json' \
--data '{}' \
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two places that document the messages API usage:

- [The "getting started" docs](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/getting-started-email-activity-api)
- [The API docs](https://sendgrid.api-docs.io/v3.0/email-activity/filter-all-messages)

However with regards to `status` query parameter, the "getting started" guide has outdated examples, which wrongly include `&query=status%3D%22bounced%22'`.

In the [query reference](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/getting-started-email-activity-api#query-reference) it is explicitly mentioned that `status` can only be one of the following:

> Valid values include "delivered","not_delivered", and "processing"

However, since sendgrid also relies on its own `/messages` API to retrieve values in the GUI, inspecting the traffic revealed it uses the `type` query param to identify bounces (see image below).

**Disclaimer:** This `type` parameter does not seem to be documented so use it at your own risk.

**Further reading:** If you want to be informed about failed email-events in a reactive way without periodically polling the `/messages` endpoint, you should checkout sendgrid's [webhooks mechanism](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/tracking-events/event), which will call an endpoint of your choice in order to deliver information about the email status to you, including whether it bounced or not.

[image]

Comment: Forgot to update this question before, we went with webhooks in the end :) I'll mark your answer as the accepted one. Ta!

Comment: Thanks :) Yeah, with sengrid using webhooks is usually the better approach to track and respond to email delivery failures.

Comment: As another side note for anyone reading this - we used "SubUsers" to get specific webhooks for each application. We were previously reluctant to use webhooks because we didn't know this was possible and thought we'd get flooded with *loads* of webhooks that weren't relevant to the specific application.